# Failing to render a header on GitHub

Tags: github, browser, markdown

Here's my `README.md` in a GitHub repo:

```
###This is a Header
This is not a Header
```

Both lines render as plain text. The first one should render as a Header and I remember it did previously.

I have no idea what's wrong with my browsers (Chrome on macOS), I've tried Firefox and Opera but nothing helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's not a problem of your browser. I found the same "bug", too.

GitHub just update their markdown renderer to CommonMark: https://github.com/blog/2333-a-formal-spec-for-github-flavored-markdown

and CommonMark requires that **a space character** be between the `#` characters and the title: `### Header`

```
###This is not a Header
### This is a Header
```

[image]

Though most of my MarkDown editor (Typora, MacDown) render them Header:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put a space after #. It seems that's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the new specification](https://github.github.com/gfm/#atx-headings), for the ATX-style headings (emphasis mine):

> The opening sequence of `#` characters **must be followed by a space** or by the end of line.
>
> ...
>
> At least one space is required between the `#` characters and the
>   heading’s contents, unless the heading is empty. Note that many
>   implementations currently do not require the space. However, the space
>   was required by the [original ATX
>   implementation](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/atx/atx.py)...